# DOM Changed Event Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, events, firefox, firefox-addon

So I have created a Firefox extension and it works great, however when I submitted it (although it was accepted) it came up with one security warning. It said setTimeout() was removed in an else clause.

So, is there a way to listen for any DOM change? (or even a specific element changing, I have an ID for both). However, divs do not have an onChange event so any ideas?

I don't mind if it's ANY change, doesn't have to be div-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DOMSubtreeModified` event sound like something you want to use. Keep in mind, that it is deprecated and after some time its support will probably be removed from browsers.

http://help.dottoro.com/ljrmcldi.php

Comment: Thanks - Quick question; if I have a div and attached that event handler, if that div was changed would it trigger the event or only that div's children?

Comment: Test ;) I often just add global listener on document, and then check for evt.target's tagName and id.

Comment: Unfortunately Mozilla don't like this either :( Due to it being depreciated, it suggested not using it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out adding an "onChange" event to a div works fine, although it might not be W3C valid it doesn't really matter as it's only a Firefox extension (plus it works!).